# the Bessel function Integration

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, symbolic, special-functions

I try to calculate the integral of the Bessel function in Matlab

```
syms a r b k
L=int(log(r) * (besselj(0,a * r)+b * bessely(0,a * r)),k,1)
```

but I have this error (Invalid limits given : (k, 1)) i.e. I have a problem in log(r) but the k checks (0<k<1) I don't know how I can set this condition (0<k<1) to get the correct result. how can I calculate this integral with this condition in Mathematica?

Comment: Hi, I can't calculate this integral in MATLAB 
So I tried with Mathematica. So yes how can I calculate this integral with this condition in Mathematica

Comment: When posting questions here, include the Mathematica code so that we can copy and paste.

Comment: ok.  I will include the Mathematica code, for the next time because this is my first time in mathematics.

Comment: Since you get an error message, you must have run some Mathematica/Wolfram Language code, so edit your question and add it. If this is your first time, why not read the documentation for [`Integrate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integrate.html) and [`BesselJ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BesselJ.html).

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi I believe by "error" OP means error in MATLAB…

Comment: Then, to OP: Hello, welcome to Mathematica.SE. I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]. 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/).

Comment: @xzczd thank you very much, Sir.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$$\int_k^1 \ln (r) (J_0(a r)+b Y_0(a r)) \, dr=\int_k^1 \ln (r) J_0(a r) \, dr+\int_k^1 \ln (r) b Y_0(a r) \, dr$$

Mathematica have problems to compute the second define integral.

One way is:

```
$Version
(*"13.1.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)"*)

Integrate[Log[r]*BesselJ[0, a*r], {r, k, 1}, 
Assumptions -> {0 < k < 1, a ∈ Reals}] + (D[
  Integrate[r^q*b*BesselY[0, a*r], {r, k, 1}, 
   Assumptions -> {0 < k < 1, b ∈ Reals, q >= 0}], q] /. 
 q -> 0) // Simplify // Expand

(*-BesselJ[0, a] + k*BesselJ[0, a*k] - (a^2*HypergeometricPFQ[{3/2, 3/2}, 
{2, 5/2, 5/2}, -1/4*a^2])/18 + (a^2*k^3*HypergeometricPFQ[{3/2, 3/2}, {2, 
5/2, 5/2}, -1/4*(a^2*k^2)])/18 - 
 k*BesselJ[0, a*k]*Log[k] - b*Pi*BesselY[0, a]*StruveH[-1, a] + 
 (b*Pi*BesselY[0, a]*PolyGamma[0, 3/2]*StruveH[-1, a])/2 + 
 b*k*Pi*BesselY[0, a*k]*StruveH[-1, a*k] - 
 (b*k*Pi*BesselY[0, a*k]*Log[k]*StruveH[-1, a*k])/2 - (b*k*Pi*BesselY[0, 
 a*k]*PolyGamma[0, 3/2]*StruveH[-1, a*k])/2 - (Pi*BesselJ[1, a]*StruveH[0, 
 a])/2 - 
 b*Pi*BesselY[1, a]*StruveH[0, a] + (b*Pi*BesselY[1, a]*PolyGamma[0, 
 3/2]*StruveH[0, a])/2 + (k*Pi*BesselJ[1, a*k]*StruveH[0, a*k])/2 + 
 b*k*Pi*BesselY[1, a*k]*StruveH[0, a*k] - 
 (k*Pi*BesselJ[1, a*k]*Log[k]*StruveH[0, a*k])/2 - (b*k*Pi*BesselY[1, 
 a*k]*Log[k]*StruveH[0, a*k])/2 - (b*k*Pi*BesselY[1, a*k]*PolyGamma[0, 
 3/2]*StruveH[0, a*k])/2 + 
 (Pi*BesselJ[0, a]*StruveH[1, a])/2 - (k*Pi*BesselJ[0, a*k]*StruveH[1, 
 a*k])/2 + (k*Pi*BesselJ[0, a*k]*Log[k]*StruveH[1, a*k])/2 + 
 (b*Pi*BesselY[0, a]*Derivative[{0}, {0, 1}, 0] 
 [HypergeometricPFQRegularized][{1}, {1/2, 3/2}, -1/4*a^2])/4 - 
 (b*k*Pi*BesselY[0, a*k]*Derivative[{0}, {0, 1}, 0] 
 [HypergeometricPFQRegularized][{1}, {1/2, 3/2}, -1/4*(a^2*k^2)])/4 + 
 (a*b*Pi*BesselY[1, a]*Derivative[{0}, {0, 1}, 0] 
 [HypergeometricPFQRegularized][{1}, {3/2, 3/2}, -1/4*a^2])/8 - 
 (a*b*k^2*Pi*BesselY[1, a*k]*Derivative[{0}, {0, 1}, 0] 
 [HypergeometricPFQRegularized][{1}, {3/2, 3/2}, -1/4*(a^2*k^2)])/8 + 
 (b*Pi*BesselY[0, a]*Derivative[{0}, {1, 0}, 0] 
 [HypergeometricPFQRegularized][{1}, {1/2, 3/2}, -1/4*a^2])/4 - 
 (b*k*Pi*BesselY[0, a*k]*Derivative[{0}, {1, 0}, 0] 
 [HypergeometricPFQRegularized][{1}, {1/2, 3/2}, -1/4*(a^2*k^2)])/4 + 
 (a*b*Pi*BesselY[1, a]*Derivative[{0}, {1, 0}, 0] 
 [HypergeometricPFQRegularized][{1}, {3/2, 3/2}, -1/4*a^2])/8 - 
 (a*b*k^2*Pi*BesselY[1, a*k]*Derivative[{0}, {1, 0}, 0] 
 [HypergeometricPFQRegularized][{1}, {3/2, 3/2}, -1/4*(a^2*k^2)])/8*)

  % /. a -> 1 /. b -> 1 /. k -> 1/2 // N
  (*-0.0986857*)
```

Another way using `MellinTransfrom`:

```
 Integrate[Log[r]*BesselJ[0, a*r], {r, k, 1}, 
 Assumptions -> {0 < k < 1, a ∈ Reals}] + 
 InverseMellinTransform[Integrate[
  MellinTransform[Log[r]*b*BesselY[0, a*r], a, s], {r, k, 1}, 
  Assumptions -> {0 < k < 1, b ∈ Reals, s > 0}] // 
  Expand, s, a] // Simplify // Expand

 (*-BesselJ[0, a] + k BesselJ[0, a k] - 
 1/18 a^2 HypergeometricPFQ[{3/2, 3/2}, {2, 5/2, 5/2}, -(a^2/4)] + 
 1/18 a^2 k^3 HypergeometricPFQ[{3/2, 3/2}, {2, 5/2, 5/
2}, -(1/4) a^2 k^2] - k BesselJ[0, a k] Log[k] - 
  1/4 b MeijerG[{{}, {1/2, 1/2}}, {{-(1/2), 0, 0}, {-(1/2)}}, a/2, 1/
 2] + 1/4 b k MeijerG[{{}, {1/2, 1/2}}, {{-(1/2), 0, 
 0}, {-(1/2)}}, (a k)/2, 1/2] - 
  1/4 b k Log[
 k] MeijerG[{{}, {1/2, 1/2}}, {{-(1/2), 0, 0}, {-(1/2)}}, (a 
 k)/2, 1/2] + 1/
 2 b k Log[k] MeijerG[{{}, {1/2, 1/2}}, {{-(1/2), 0, 1}, {-(1/2)}}, 
 (
 a k)/2, 1/2] - 1/2 π BesselJ[1, a] StruveH[0, a] + 
 1/2 k π BesselJ[1, a k] StruveH[0, a k] - 
 1/2 k π BesselJ[1, a k] Log[k] StruveH[0, a k] + 
 1/2 π BesselJ[0, a] StruveH[1, a] - 
 1/2 k π BesselJ[0, a k] StruveH[1, a k] + 
 1/2 k π BesselJ[0, a k] Log[k] StruveH[1, a k]*)


  % /. a -> 1 /. b -> 1 /. k -> 1/2 // N
  (*-0.0986857*)
  NIntegrate[Log[r]*(BesselJ[0, a*r] + b*BesselY[0, a*r]) /. a -> 1 /. b -> 1, {r,1/2, 1}]
  (*-0.0986857*)
```

Comment: Nice use of the Mellin transformation!

Comment: @Mariusz Iwaniuk,  thank  you  very much

Comment: @xzczd thank you very much, Sir

Answer (score 4):

In Mathematica you could write this:

```
L = Integrate[Log[r]*(BesselJ[0,a*r]+b*BesselY[0,a*r]),{r,k,1},
              Assumptions->{0<k<1,a>0}]
```

It evaluates to something, but the result may look a bit terrifying. I have also assumed `a>0` as you can see, I do not exactly know what your assumptions are.

**Edit/Remark.** The following integral is evaluated without assumptions on `a`:

```
Integrate[Log[r]*BesselJ[0,a*r],{r,k,1},
          Assumptions->{0<k<1}]
```

Comment: I have (a, b) just a constant  a=constant, not a>0

Comment: The constant `b` is no problem because it appears linearly. I used `a>0` for the following reason: Allowing `a==0` does not make much sense since `BesselY[0,0]` is undefined/infinite. For `a<0` there is the problem that `BesselY[0,z]` has a branch cut discontinuity along the negative real line (`z<0`) and so on, so the answer is not clearcut.

Comment: ok, a is the root of the Bessel function i.e. BesselJ(0,a_k)=0 for k=1,2,3..... but for example, Matlab doesn't know this so I need to use symbolic calculation with a=constant and after considering a =the root of the Bessel function

Comment: The roots of the Bessel function are typically understood to be positive (since the argument of Bessel is typically a radius in applications) and then you would be in the `a>0` case. Btw, in Mathematica you can get say $a_5$ using `BesselJZero[0,5]`.

Comment: ok thank you  very much